# Select box option value checked

Tags: php, html

How to check and find match a select box's value against a series of PHP arrays e.g

```
<select id="person" name="person">
<option value="jane">Jane</option>
<option value="julia">Julia</option>
</select>
```

PHP arrays

```
$person_1 = ["Id"=> "1", "name"=>"Jane", "age"=>"23" ]
$person_2 = ["Id"=> "2", "name"=>"Julia", "age"=>"29"]
```

If user select jane then check the value against these two arrays. If it matches with one print the age of that particular person.

Comment: Don't use separate variables, use a multi-dimensional array. And your syntax for associative arrays is wrong, `=` should be `=>`.

Comment: The array is generated by for-each loop. Any hint for me?

Comment: How is a loop creating variables with different names instead of pushing them all onto a single array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a multi-dimensional array so you can loop through it to find the matching name.

```
$people = [
    ["Id" => "1", "name"=>"Jane", "age"=>"23" ],
    ["Id" => "2", "name"=>"Julia", "age"=>"29"]
];

foreach ($people as $person) {
    if ($person['name'] == $_POST['person']) {
        echo "Age is {$person['age']}";
        break;
    }
}
```

Any time you find yourself creating variables with numeric names like `$person1` and `$person2`, it's a sure sign that you should be using an array to collect them all into a single variable.

If there will be lots of people, it would be more efficient to make `$people` an associative array:

```
$people = [
    "Jane" => ["Id" => "1", "name"=>"Jane", "age"=>"23" ],
    "Julia" => ["Id" => "2", "name"=>"Julia", "age"=>"29"]
];
```

Then you don't need a loop, just do:

```
$person = $people[$_POST['name']];
```

Comment: Thank you. But  the main problem is how to check the select box's value against the arrays. If isset the value "jane" then check it in the arrays and after that if it exists in array then print the age or id.

Comment: The select box's value is in `$_POST['person']`, my code tests that against the array.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.